# ASPX.NET AD Authentication with IIS No longer working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, active-directory, iis-7

I have a site runing inside our domain servers witha firewall for external access. It popups up a login box for you to put your AD credentials. This is all how it is supposed to work. But since this week it no longer considers it valid. Users that were able to connetc last week no longer can connect. we all get 401 errors in the IIS 7 log. Is there a way to trace where this is broken?
the server Windows Server 2016 DataCenter.
This is our Web.config:

```
 <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime />
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="SEC_DB_EMAILMANAGER_ADMIN" />
      <allow users=".\egadmin" />
      <deny users="*" />
    </authorization>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0">
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
        <identity impersonate="false" />
  </system.web>
```

In the Authorization section of IIS WE have these settings:

```
Anonymous Access:     Enabled  - with specific user:IUSR 
Basic Authentication: Enabled - no settings set
```

The others are all disabled. I tried changing different settings and it doesn't seem to work. we have an automated deployment process that deployed something last week it is possibles some settings were changed we didn't realize

Comment: One 401 error when a new session starts is normal. That's what tells the browser to prompt for credentials. So it's normal to see that in the logs. But if you put in your credentials and get *another* 401 back, then that means your credentials were rejected (in the IIS logs you would see a second 401 go back). Are you sure the second one is a 401 and not 403? (Still a problem, but a different one)

Answer (score 0):

After a day & a half we figured out the problem. When IT Support was adding the last batch of users to the SECURITY GROUP  The SAML ( PRE 2000 name) name was renamed to something else, which is used for iis lookup